# jVectorMap change color with click for 2 areas max

Tags: javascript, bundle, jvectormap

Can someone help me with jVectorMap for selecting 2 regions max. There are 2 options available for region color, they could be green or they could be red. Only one region can be green at the time and the same for the red region. So, one region green and one region red.
If I click in the green region it should become the normal region color for example(#ccc) as all the other regions, the same happen when I click in the red region.
If I click in any #ccc region while exists red and green region nothing should happen. But if I click in a #ccc region while no green or no red regions the clicked region must become or green or red.
Here is an example of the function that I want to add to jVectorMap, you can just copy and paste in your html to check.

```
<style>
    .no_color_toggle{ float:left; margin:10px; background:#ccc; width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer; }
    .green_color_toggle{ float:left; margin:10px; background:green; width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer; }
    .red_color_toggle{ float:left; margin:10px; background:red; width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer; }
</style>
<script>
function toggleClass(el){
    var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
    var num_toggle_g = document.getElementsByClassName("green_color_toggle").length;
    var num_toggle_p = document.getElementsByClassName("red_color_toggle").length;
    if(el.className == "no_color_toggle"){
        if( num_toggle_g == 0){
            el.className = "green_color_toggle";
        }else if( num_toggle_g == 1 && num_toggle_p ==0){
            el.className = "red_color_toggle";
        }
    }else if (el.className == "green_color_toggle"){
        el.className = "no_color_toggle";
    }else if (el.className == "red_color_toggle"){
        el.className = "no_color_toggle";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="menu1">
    <p>This is just an example, pretend that each block is a country in jVectorMap. What I want is to do the same logic as this for the world map</p>
    <div class="green_color_toggle" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="no_color_toggle" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="no_color_toggle" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
    <div class="red_color_toggle" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *...clicked region must become or green or red*... How do You decide what color will be?

Comment: It is like a trip maker, you select the one you are and the one you will go. You need to select 2 of them of course, the departure place(Green) and arrivals(Red). In the initial stage we have one green and one red already selected, for example, US and Mexico. If the user clicks on the green color, the green color will become #ccc and the user can click in any #ccc color to make it green. If the user clicks in the both green and red, all the map will become #ccc color as in the example and the next country the user selects will become green and after that the following one would be red. Got it?

Comment: OK, finally the sequence of region selection does matter, You need to store also that sequence, is this true?

Comment: Yes, it matters. The person could choose US green, Mexico red and that would mean the person would fly from US to Mexico. If the person chooses US red and Mexico green, that would mean the person would fly from Mexico to US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in jVectorMap selection cannot be used for this task, because *regions* and *markers* are JavaScript objects (not arrays) , so the selection sequence is not guaranteed to be the correct one. It will be much simpler to set a custom selection inside the `click` handler.

So, You need to implement Your own selection array. To do that, simply add two custom parameters containing Your data. The logic behind the *selection* criterias will be also very simple to implement, if You store that selection sequence.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {

  function setSelection(code) {
    var a = 'fill', p = this.params, 
      colors = p.selectedColors, regions = p.travelRegions,
      initial = p.regionStyle.initial[a];
    var e = this.series.regions[0].elements[code].element,
      shape = e.shape, status = e.config.style.selected;
                                        
    var i = colors.indexOf(status[a]);
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
      case 1: 
        regions[i] = ''; status[a] = initial;
        break;
      default:
        switch(true) {
          case regions[0] == '' && regions[1] == '':
          case regions[0] == '' && regions[1] != '':
            regions[0] = code; status[a] = colors[0];
            break;
          case regions[0] != '' && regions[1] == '':
            regions[1] = code; status[a] = colors[1];
            break;
          default:; /* departure & arrival already selected */
        }
    }
    shape.updateStyle();
    for(var n=0; n<regions.length; n++) {
      if(regions[n] != '') this.setSelectedRegions(regions[n]);
    }                
  }

  var worldMap = new jvm.Map({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    container: $('#world-map'),
    zoomOnScroll: true,
    backgroundColor: 'aliceblue', 
    travelRegions: ['',''],
    selectedColors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00'],
    series: {regions: [{values: {}}]}, 
    onRegionClick: function(e, code) {
      setSelection.call(worldMap, code);
    }
  });   
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```